# how to make a selection more specific?

Tags: html, css

Why does this work:

```
.move {-moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;}
.one:hover .move {-moz-transform: scale(0.5);}
```

While this doesn't:

```
.move {-moz-transition: scale 1s ease-out;}
.one:hover .move {-moz-transform: scale(0.5);}
```

I don't want to select "all" - I only want to select the attribute i want to change (I posted only the `-moz-` prefix to keep the code shorter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `transition` property supposed to use the property name, in this case you need to use  `transition: tranform 1s ease-out;` to make it work. Like below:

```
.move {-moz-transition: transform 1s ease-out;}
.one:hover .move {-moz-transform: scale(0.5);}
```

***note***: if it doesn't work try to use  `transition: -moz-tranform 1s ease-out;` instead